# How to fully evaluate case block in type

Tags: dependent-type, idris, type-level-computation

In Idris you can have complex computations in the types themselves, like a case block in this function:

```
fun_1 : (n : Nat) -> case n of { Z => Bool; _ => Nat}
fun_1 Z = True
fun_1 (S n) = S n
```

But how would you be able to fully evaluate such a result, given a `n : Nat` (which would evaluate into `Bool` or `Nat`)?

For reference I have this function definition:

```
fun_2 : (n : Nat) -> n = Z -> Bool
fun_2 n nEqZ = ?fun_2_rhs
```

How could I implement this function using `fun_1` so that it typechecks?

I tried the following two approaches, which both gave an error:

```
fun_2 : (n : Nat) -> n = Z -> Bool
fun_2 n nEqZ = rewrite nEqZ in (fun_1 n)
```

This gave the error

> When elaborating right hand side of fun_2: rewrite did not change type
>   Bool

```
fun_2 : (n : Nat) -> n = Z -> Bool
fun_2 n nEqZ = replace nEqZ {P=(\nat => case nat of { Z => Bool; _ => Nat})} (fun_1 n)
```

And this gave the error

> When elaborating right hand side of fun_2:
>   When elaborating an application of function replace:
>
> ```
> Can't unify
>     case block in fun_1 n n (Type of fun_1 n)
> with
>     (\__pi_arg => Bool) n (Expected type)
>
> Specifically:
>     Can't unify
>         case block in fun_1 n n
>     with
>         Bool
> ```

Is the only possible way for it to typecheck to pattern match on `Z` and call `fun_1 Z` directly, like this?:

```
fun_2 : (n : Nat) -> n = Z -> Bool
fun_2 Z Refl = fun_1 Z
```

I am not very convinced by this method, because the computation in the type can be more complex than a simple pattern case analysis on `Z` and `S n`, and I'm not sure it would be possible (or at least straightforward) in those cases

Answer (score 3):

If you want computation in the type to make progress, it needs some information, so yes, you do need to pattern match. The rewrite didn't work because nothing in the type had the form `n=Z`.

Quite often, using a computation in a type like this gives some useful hints as to how the corresponding program should work, suggesting where to check for errors etc.